# How to extend the class kartik\dynagrid\DynaGrid?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, kartik-v, yii2-dynagrid

Installed the `DynaGrid` plugin and ran into the problem of expanding it. I created my own class `DynaGridViewAdvanced`, which is located on the path `modules/appWidgets/widgets/grid` and has namespace `app\modules\appWidgets\widgets\grid`.

The class code is as follows:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace app\modules\appWidgets\widgets\grid;

use kartik\dynagrid\DynaGrid;
use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Url;

class DynaGridViewAdvanced extends DynaGrid {
    /**
     * @var bool активность функции перехода на просмотр при двойном клике
     */
    public $transitionToView = false;
    
    public function init() {
        parent::init(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        
        if ($this->transitionToView && empty($this->rowOptions)) {
            $this->rowOptions = function($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                $viewLink = Url::toRoute(['/' . Yii::$app->controller->id . '/view']);
                
                return ['ondblclick' => 'location.href="' . $viewLink . '?id="+(this.dataset.key);'];
            };
        }
    }
    
    public function run() {
        parent::run(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Actually, the question is why the error is thrown out and how to fix it?

> View not Found – yii\base\ViewNotFoundException
>
> The view file does not exist: /var/www/urs/modules/appWidgets/widgets/grid/views/config.php

In `DynaGrid` itself there is a property `_module`, which stores in itself `kartik\dynagrid\Module`, in which there is a property `configView`. `configView` is used only in `DynaGrid` itself:

```
$dynagrid = $this->render(
    $this->_module->configView,
    [...]
)
```

As far as I understand the error, he is trying to find this configuration view file exactly with `namespace`.

See the full error page:

[image]

Comment: what line does it throw this error on add the full stack trace

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam added image, but with bad quality. Error in: `/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php` line 233. Its try to find `view/config.php` in my own directory, but not in source....

Comment: The `Widget::render()` method uses the widget class as view context and default implementation of its `getViewPath()` points to `views` subfolder where your class is. You should probably override the `getViewPath()` method and use `ReflectionClass::getParentClass()` to point to proper location. See the `getViewPath()` implementation here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Widget.php#L256